# Can anyone read adb logcat errors on my react native android release apk?

Tags: firebase, react-native, logcat

I am having problem with the release apk of my react native android app, on development it works fine but on release it crashes upon launch. I know there are lots of similar questions like this but it differs from app to app. The last time i build a release apk 4 months ago it was working fine, the only thing I did was upgrade my dependencies and now the app crash on launch, when I click the app it closes right away.

here is my logcat but I don't know how to read these errors, can anyone help?

```
$ adb logcat -s System.err
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width must be > 0
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkWidthHeight(Bitmap.java:587)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1021)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:954)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at com.android.contacts.hap.AcountDataManagerImpl$LoaderThread.getScaledBitmap(AccountsDataManager.java:1064)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at com.android.contacts.hap.AcountDataManagerImpl$LoaderThread.populateAccountIndexMap(AccountsDataManager.java:978)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at com.android.contacts.hap.AcountDataManagerImpl$LoaderThread.handleMessage(AccountsDataManager.java:699)
03-01 21:34:55.900 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
03-01 21:34:55.901 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-01 21:34:55.901 12541 12593 W System.err:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

and here is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.14.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^10.8.1",
    "@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake": "^1.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.4",
    "react-native-android-pip": "git+https://github.com/shaun-chiang/rn-android-pip.git",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.3",
    "react-native-incall-manager": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-simple-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-url-preview": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.87.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out the why my app is crashing, it's because I upgraded Android build.gradle to 4.1.0, it seems that the current version of react native which is 0.63.4 is not compatible with Android build.gradle 4.1 and higher. When I downgrade my Android Studio to 4.0.2 my app finally opens.